# Understanding distribution of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to better understand the solution to this given problem:

Given X and Y as independent variables, where $X \in U(-1,1) \ and \ Y$ assumes values +1 and -1 with probability 1/2. Need to show $Z=X+Y \in U(-2,2) $

The solution goes as this : $F_Z = P(Z\leq z) = P(Z\leq z | Y=-1)\cdot P(Y=-1) + P(Z\leq z |Y=1)\cdot P(Y=1)$

**I would like to clarify here : how can the probability of Z be the above without considering X?**

Although the solution continues from above as this :

$= P(X \leq z+1)\cdot 1/2 + P(X \leq z-1)\cdot 1/2$

I understand that it is using the total law of probability but am a bit confused behind the reasons/rules of doing the above although Z is a sum of the above 2 random variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution goes as this : $F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z) = P(Z\leq z \mid Y=-1)\cdot P(Y=-1) + P(Z\leq z \mid Y=1)\cdot P(Y=1)$
>
> **I would like to clarify here : how can the probability of Z be the above without considering X?**

That's just the law of total probability:  $~\mathsf P(A) $ $=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement)\\=\mathsf P(A\mid B)\,\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)\,\mathsf P(B^\complement)$

The probability of a union of disjoint events is the sum of the probabilities of each event.

There is nothing much more to it than that.

The events here are when $\{Z\leq z, Y=-1\}$ and when $\{Z\leq z, Y=+1\}$.

Because $Z=X+Y$ then these events are also $\{X\leq z+1, Y=-1\}$ and $\{X\leq z-1, Y=+1\}$

Since, when $Y=-1$ then $Z$ being less than $z$ means $X$ is less than $z+1$

---

The reason for doing this is simple:   We know the distribution functions of $X,Y$, and wish to find the distribution function of $Z$ in terms of them.   Since $Y$ is discrete so partitioning on it is easier.   Thus we apply the LoTP.
$$F_Z(z)= F_{X\mid Y=-1}(z+1)\,P_Y(-1)+F_{X\mid Y=1}(z-1)\,P_Y(1)$$

Now since $X,Y$ are independent, that simplifies to:

$$F_Z(z)= F_{X}(z+1)\,P_Y(-1)+F_{X}(z-1)\,P_Y(1)$$

And because $P_Y(y) = \tfrac 12 \mathbf 1_{Y\in\{-1,1\}}$ we have:

$$F_Z(z)= \tfrac 12\big(F_{X}(z+1)+F_{X}(z-1)\big)$$

Finally, $X$ is uniformly distributed over $(-1;1)$, so:

$$\begin{align}F_Z(z) ~&=~ \tfrac 14(\mathbf 1_{z+1\in(-1;1)}+\mathbf 1_{z-1\in (-1;1)}) \\[1ex] &=~ \tfrac 14~\mathbf 1_{z\in(-2;0)\cup(0;2)}\end{align}$$

Which means $Z\sim\mathcal U (-2;2){\setminus}\{0\}$.   That is uniformly distributed *almost everywhere* on the interval $(-2;2)$.

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than approach the question directly, let's consider a simpler question.  Suppose $X$ is either $0$ or $2$ with probability $1/2$ each, and $Y$ is either $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each, and we ask what the distribution of the sum $Z = X+Y$ is.

In that case, we could definitely write something like

$$
P(Z = z) = P(Z = z \mid Y = 0) \cdot P(Y = 0) + P(Z = z \mid Y = 1) \cdot P(Y = 1)
$$

which doesn't explicitly involve $X$.  This is simply the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), since there are only two possible cases for $Y$, and we exhaust them.  We could then go on to write

$$
P(Z = z) = P(X = z \mid Y = 0) \cdot P(Y = 0) + P(X = z-1 \mid Y = 1) \cdot P(Y = 1)
$$

which is the same as above, but now takes advantage of our knowledge that $Z = X+Y$.

The same sort of evaluation is taking place in your original problem.